# If it possible to filter out names of objects returned in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-cms

For my Django CMS Admin I would like to prevent it returning a specific object to the CMS.  What is the best way to do this?

I would like to do something like

```
class MyModuleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name']
    list_filter = ('my_module__name__is_not=moduleidontwant',)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply overload `get_queryset` admin function and filter out items you do not want:

```py
class MyModuleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name']

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super(MyModuleAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        return queryset.exclude(name='moduleidontwant')
```

Comment: thanks this is an excellent and efficient solution

Answer (score 0):

```
# custom_filters.py
from django.contrib.admin import SimpleListFilter

class testFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    """ This filter is being used in django admin panel in specified model."""
    title = 'Title of you field'
    parameter_name = 'field_name'
    
    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
       if not self.value():
           return queryset
       else:
           return queryset.filter(my_module__name__is_not='moduleidontwant') #add your filter here.
```

Add this testFilter in your `list_filter` in admin.py file.

```
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *
from .custom_filters import testFilter

class MyModuleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name']
    list_filter = (testFilter)
```

You can use this reference in case you get stuck in between
https://www.dothedev.com/blog/django-admin-list_filter/